# How to have two versions of an event handler?

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I have an event handler subscribed to the FormClosing event. This event handler provides dialog for the user when they exit my application; like so:

```
    private void frmUavController_FormClosing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult dlgResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Exit?",
            MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (dlgResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {                
            UtilSTKScenario.PauseScenarioAnimation(UtilSTKScenario._stkObjectRoot);                
        }
        else if (dlgResult == DialogResult.No)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Because the application runs in a side-by-side fashion; injecting COM commands into another application - I want my application to exit if the application receiving COM commands is not launched (or closed during execution). This is achieved like so:

```
    static UtilSTKScenario()
    {
        // give time for active form to show
        Thread.Sleep(100);

        _stkProgramId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("stkProgramId");

        if (CheckIfStkIsLaunched())
        {
            InitAllFields();
        }
        else
        {
            HideController dHideController = new HideController(((frmUavController)Form.ActiveForm).HideControllerUi);
            ((frmUavController)Form.ActiveForm).Invoke(dHideController);
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Calling 'Application.Exit()' causes the FormClosing event to fire. This I do not want - rather, I want the application to just exit.

Any ideas ?

WulfgarPro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to look at the event args of the FormClosing event. `FormClosingEventArgs` has a `CloseReason` property that may give an indicator if the form was closed by a user directly as opposed to some other mechanism.

Though I'm not clear how `Application.Exit()` calls will appear... If it is also showing as `CloseReason.UserClosing` then you may need to add an overload to your form [e.g. SystemClose()] to close your form and use an instance variable to tell it not to prompt within your handler.

Answer (score 2):

Your FormClosing event gets a FormClosingEventArgs parameter, which has a CloseReason property. If that's CloseReason.ApplicationExitCall, then the form is closing because of a call to Application.Exit. You can just skip your "close?" prompt in that case.

```
private void frmUavController_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.ApplicationExitCall)
        return;
    // ...
```

Comment: I cant seem to find this 'CloseReason' property. The e is of type CancelEventArgs not FormClosingEventArgs?

Comment: FormClosingEventArgs is a subclass of CancelEventArgs. I just swapped them around and it works great. You need to change the type of 'e' in your code above.

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to handle this sort of thing (bypass normal "do you want to close?" checks) is to use a Boolean variable. Name it something like `_forceExit`, set it to true if the external event forces you to close, and if it's true, skip the dialog box in your Closing event.

Comment: this worked for me, but your other answer I found to be more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Can you look at the sender object? My guess is that the sender object is different depending on you actually close the form or call the `Application.Exit()` method.

Comment: my current solution is to use a flagging variable. I will look at the sender now. Thanks!

Comment: sender is always the active form object; in this case - frmUavController.